# Angular directive: rescale images, update when ngSrc changes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, html5-canvas

I've got an Angular directive which currently does its job when the load event is triggered:

```
.directive("testDir", [
    function() {
        return {
            link: function(scope, elm, attrs) {
                    ...
                return elm.one("load", function() {
                    return ...
                });
            }
        };
    }
]);
```

this directive is added to an `<img>` tag, which is sourced from `ng-src`.
The directive is supposed to shrink down the image in size, to achieve better performance on mobile devices.

Now my question: I want that the directive function is triggered not `.one()` time, but after each time the linked variable (via `{{}}`) of the `ng-src` does change. How can I realize that?

I want the directive to be as independent as possible, so I'd prefer it to have no explicit variable names of the underlying controller in it.

Comment: attrs.$observe should help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT 2**

Alright here it is with canvas instead of css.  You should get the idea.  I made it a full element directive since I was using two parameters - percent and url:

*script.js*

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller("MyCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.i = 0;
  $scope.urls = ["_71832498_71825880.jpg",
    "0411_hubble_970-630x420.jpg"
  ]
  $scope.changePic = function() {
    if ($scope.i == 0) {
      $scope.i = 1;
      return;
    }
    if ($scope.i == 1) {
      $scope.i = 0;
      return;
    }
  }
})

myApp.directive("scaleImage", [
  '$http',
  function($http) {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        percent: '&',
        url: '&',
      },
      template: '<img ng-src="{{ src }}" />',
      link: function (scope, elm, attrs) {
        var img;

        scope.$watch(function () {
          // Because we're returning an object we need to deep watch.  Do this sparingly.
          // Doing this on large arrays or objects can be ill-performant, but I think this
          // is fine here.
          return {
            percent: scope.percent(),
            url: scope.url(),
          }
        }, function (value) {
          if (!value.percent || !value.url) {
            return;
          }

          // Remove the old one, if any.  Should hopefully fix any memory leaks related to
          // creating an element.
          if (img) {
              img.remove();
          }

          img = angular.element('<img style="display: none" src="' + value.url + '">');
          elm.append(img);

          // This will give it enough time to load the image and render the element 
          // so that it has a height and whatnot; may not be needed.  Was needed in plunker
          // at some point; can't tell on localhost, doesn't seem to hurt.
          $http.get(value.url).then(function () {
            var canvas, ctx, neededHeight, neededWidth;
            neededHeight = img[0].naturalHeight * value.percent / 100;
            neededWidth = img[0].naturalWidth * value.percent / 100;
            canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
            canvas.width = neededWidth;
            canvas.height = neededHeight;
            ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
            ctx.drawImage(img[0], 0, 0, neededWidth, neededHeight);
            scope.src = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
          });

        }, true); // true to deep watch
      }
    };
  }
]);
```

*index.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="angular.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <input type="number" ng-model="percent" ng-init="percent = 4">
    <scale-image url="urls[i]" percent="percent"></scale-image>
    <button ng-click="changePic()">Change Picture</button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

---

**EDIT**

http://plnkr.co/edit/MoEsJPRwR1nFOhRKd37q?p=preview

```
myApp.directive("scaleImage", [
  function() {
    return {
      link: function(scope, elm, attrs) {
        attrs.$observe('scaleImage', function (value) {
          elm.css('width', value + '%');
          elm.css('height', value + '%');
        });
      }
    };
  }
]);
```

Let me know if this doesn't work.

---

Can you do:

```
attrs.$observe('src' /* might be `ngSrc` */, function (value) { /* this is executed when the interpolated value of src changes */ });
```

If that doesn't work can you set up a plunker or fiddle?

Comment: I've set up a plnkr... The only problem is that the directive involves canvas drawing and plnkr does not seem to support it. Anyway, you'll get the idea. The directive is supposed to resize the picture.
[PLNKR here](http://plnkr.co/edit/9oY1EqctOovJ6OhwWovp?p=preview)

Comment: Can you post the link?

Comment: I'm sorry, yes: [PLNKR here](http://plnkr.co/edit/9oY1EqctOovJ6OhwWovp?p=preview)

Comment: This is pretty nice, however, I wanted to use the canvas to redraw the image, to get a lower resolution of the images. Because performance matters on mobile devices. CSS keeps the original resolution I think.

Comment: @Clawish: Are you concerned about data usage - because I think your code transfers the entire image to get the original height and width - or like RAM/having the entire image loaded on the page?

Comment: Well this JS code will be used in a Cordova app. It seems that the higher the resolution of the displayed pictures is, the slower the app responds. So I wanted to use this directive to scale them down.

Comment: @Clawish If you can get a sandbox working for `toDataURL` on plunker let me know and I can try to tackle the angular part - which is what your question is about - I got stuck trying to get past tainted canvases and whatnot last night (well not "stuck", just gave up/got tired).

Comment: Got stuck with the same problem... I think it's not possible beacuse of CORS... Maybe you can download the plnkr and try it in on your local machine, because there it works, when all images come from the local file system.

Comment: @Clawish I'm working on it now in my localhost - did you finish?

Comment: @Clawish Got it working on localhost.  Had to run within a server (just used an IIS VS studio project I had laying around).  Hopefully that works for you, too.

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript:

```
.directive(
  "testDir", [
    function() {
      return {
        scope: {
          imgSrc: '='
        },

        link: function(scope, elm, attrs) {
          scope.$watch(
            'imgSrc', function(newVal) {
              // here you can update whatever you want
            }
          );
        }
      };
    }
  ]
);
```

HTML:

```
<img ng-src="{{scopeModel}}" test-dir img-src="scopeModel"/>
```